# Share types or interfaces between client and 2 webservices

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi that will consume 2 webservices and have to return to the front-end one specific object. Wanted to know if it's possible to create an interface or even share types between the 3 solutions to avoid create the objects 3 times and to avoid map complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into an assembly, share between the three projects.

If you have a nuger server, you can publish it there and have each solution install that package.

Comment: I successfully installed the nuget server, but couldn't create a nuget package that would open on nuget server. I'll probably go for the AutoMapper option.